# Redirecting non-www subfolder domain to www on wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I currently have a multisite built in wordpress. The domain is set up to be:

```
http://www.domain.com
```

The microsites are set up and built out as:

```
http://www.domain.com/location-name
```

My issues are with the non-www domains. If you go to

```
http://domain.com/location-name/ or http://domain.com/location-name/about
```

it redirects to `http://www.domain.com`

I need it to redirect to `http://www.domain.com/location-name/` or `http://www.domain.com/location-name/about`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to force `www` using your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. After clearing cache too